# random Authorization error 407 using libcurl

Tags: proxy, libcurl, winhttp, proxy-authentication

i am using libcurl to do HTTP request.

The request goes through authenticated proxy.

Below are my settings with regards to proxy

```
curlResultCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXY, <proxy-server>);
curlResultCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, <port number>);

//curlResultCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

OR

```
curlResultCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
```

I cannot give user name and password for the proxy as i expect CURL to intelligently find it like how "winhttp" interface does.

I have tried both ANY and NTLM. However, at times the request goes through successfully through the proxy. At times i am getting "Authentication required: 407" during the easy perform.

Can someone tell me what i have done wrong here to see this random behavior?

Thanks for reading!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "i expect CURL to intelligently find it like how "winhttp" interface does" ?

Comment: I am new to programming with proxy involved in HTTP transfers. I assume curl will automatically fetch the user name and password for proxy authentication by itself when i execute easy_perform

Comment: From where do you expect libcurl to fetch it?